# What is the difference between the fair and capacity schedulers?

Tags: hadoop, scheduler

I am new to the world of Hadoop and want to know the difference between fair and capacity schedulers. Also when are we supposed to use each one? Please answer in a simple way because I read many things on the Internet but I don't get much from them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Fair scheduling is a method of assigning resources to jobs such that all jobs get, on average, an equal share of resources over time. When there is a single job running, that job uses the entire cluster. When other jobs are submitted, tasks slots that free up are assigned to the new jobs, so that each job gets roughly the same amount of CPU time. Unlike the default Hadoop scheduler, which forms a queue of jobs, this lets short jobs finish in reasonable time while not starving long jobs. It is also a reasonable way to share a cluster between a number of users. Finally, fair sharing can also work with job priorities - the priorities are used as weights to determine the fraction of total compute time that each job should get.

The CapacityScheduler is designed to allow sharing a large cluster while giving each organization a minimum capacity guarantee. The central idea is that the available resources in the Hadoop Map-Reduce cluster are partitioned among multiple organizations who collectively fund the cluster based on computing needs. There is an added benefit that an organization can access any excess capacity no being used by others. This provides elasticity for the organizations in a cost-effective manner.

Comment: so the capacity scheduler used when multiple organizations use the cluster to guarantee for each organization min capacity.
Also about default hadoop scheduler if short job comes after long one it will have to wait until the long one finish , right ?! because they are in a queue.

Comment: you are right ,the capacity scheduler tries to simulate a separate FIFO/priority cluster for each user and each organization, rather than performing fair sharing between all jobs. The Capacity Scheduler also supports configuring a wait time on each queue after which it is allowed to preempt other queues’ tasks if it is below its fair share.

Comment: You should mention the source when copy pasting... http://www.iosrjournals.org/iosr-jce/papers/Vol15-issue1/I01514650.pdf?id=7558

Comment: @user3484461 The `CapacityScheduler` does not support preemption.  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html says (under the Elasticity heading) "When there is demand for these resources from queues running below capacity at a future point in time, as tasks scheduled on these resources complete, they will be assigned to applications on queues running below the capacity (pre-emption is not supported)."

Comment: @user3484461, I am not sure if it is a typo or misread. The official document (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html) says Capacity Scheduler DOES SUPPORT pre-emption.

Answer (score 7):

Below is the feature-wise comparison of the two schedulers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fair Scheduler, Allocates resources pools ( by weights), with fair sharing within each pool

Capacity Scheduler, Allocates resources to pools, with FIFO scheduling within each pool

The Capacity Scheduler is designed to allow sharing a large cluster while giving each organization capacity guarantees. with the possibility to excess capacity not being used by others.