# From Spark perspective, are Yarn schedulers really different?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, scheduling

Yarn has two famous schedulers, the `Fair Scheduler` and `Capacity Scheduler`. Roughly speaking, Capacity divides the cluster into predefined queues thus guarantees the resources for each queue, Fair scheduler also divides the cluster into queues and shares resources evenly between queues and inside the queue.

Now, looking further into the details of each scheduler, we see that:

1. Each one of them allows uneven partitioning of the cluster (weights and resource fraction for Fair and percentage in capacity)
2. Each one of them supports both FIFO and FAIR in queue application scheduling
3. Both support resource usage computation based on memory and DRF

I guess both of them "grew" into this situation, where features were added to every one of them. But as of today, is there any difference between them anymore?

P.S. I am asking the question from the context of **using Yarn to manage Spark**

EDIT: after a duplicate was suggested, I will explain why, although similar, it does not fully answer the question, first, the answers are inaccurate, for instance, applications are assigned to queues, not jobs. The most informative answer there is a comparison table, which is actually taken from [quora answer](https://www.quora.com/On-what-basis-do-I-decide-between-Fair-and-Capacity-Scheduler-in-YARN), it is correct but dates back to 2014-2016, which, while taking the development progress, makes it irrelevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the fair and capacity schedulers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-fair-and-capacity-schedulers)

Comment: @user10465355 thx for pointing our the answer, please see my edit with explanation about the validity of the current question

Answer (score 1):

Nodel Labels is the main one.  If you want to run specific jobs against a set of machines that have additional capabilities (GPUs, software licenses, higher end hardware ...) then you need to use Capacity Scheduler for now.  Fair Scheduler might get this later on but AFAIK it's still in progress.

The relevant JIRAs are:

- [YARN-8689 Support partition fairness in fair scheduler strict node label](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-8689)
- [YARN-7444 Add non-exclusive node labels for fair scheduler](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-7444)
- [YARN-6636 Fair Scheduler: respect node labels at resource request level](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-6636)
- [YARN-2492 Allow for (admin) labels on nodes and resource-requests](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2492)

As far as history, Capacity Scheduler originated from Yahoo! then was maintained by HortonWorks when Yahoo! spun off HortonWorks.  Cloudera invested in Fair Scheduler.  I'm not sure what the future is as HortonWorks and Cloudera have merged.

Comment: I have scheduled tasks against specific nodes using fair-scheduler already. It took some fudging, since the implementation was broken, but in a custom app it worked, and you could probably patch Spark to do the same.